# Concordancia de género usando "de lo más"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, concordancia-gramatical

Acabo de escribir un comentario con el siguiente ejemplo:

> Su llegada fue de lo más inoportuna.

En este caso he pensado que se debía escribir *inoportuna* en femenino por concordancia con *llegada*. ¿Pero es eso correcto? Si lo pienso, la siguiente opción también me suena correcta:

> Su llegada fue de lo más inoportuno.

En este caso se usaría el masculino por concordancia con *lo*. Nótese que en esta otra variante sí se usaría el femenino sin duda:

> Su llegada fue la más inoportuna.

E incluso esta otra variante tampoco admite discusión, y me inclina a pensar en que realmente el adjetivo debe concordar con *lo*:

> Su llegada fue de las más inoportunas.

Así pues, cuando el adjetivo se introduce con "de lo más", ¿debe concordar con *lo*, o con el sustantivo al que intenta modificar? ¿O son correctas ambas opciones?

Nota: en plural también me suenan bien ambas opciones:

> Sus llegadas fueron de lo más inoportunas.
> Sus llegadas fueron de lo más inoportuno.

Comment: Se le ha pirado la pinza al sistema de Spanish.se y hay un duplicado de esta pregunta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35752/5481 (mientras que esta es https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35753/5481) Los IDs de las preguntas son distintos 35752 y 35753. Algo muy _raruno_ ha pasado aquí, que no creo que merezca pregunta de Meta para investigar un bug.

Comment: @Diego ya he borrado la otra. Esta pregunta está publicada desde la aplicación móvil de Stack Exchange, pero al intentar publicarla la primera vez la aplicación me hizo un extraño y me volvió a la pantalla de edición. Comprobé que no se había publicado, así que la completé y publiqué otra vez, y entonces sí me llegó la confirmación. Se ve que al final llegaron las dos.

Comment: Y @Charlie ha borrado la pregunta equivocada (es decir, aquella en la que yo estaba escribiendo una respuesta :D). Para añadir al *bug report* que no se va a redactar, al mandar la respuesta aquí he tenido que resolver un captcha, cosa que nunca me había pasado en SE.

Comment: @wimi lo siento, menudo jaleo. He borrado la que aún no se había votado positivo. :-D

Comment: @Charlie se me pasó por la cabeza votarte en las dos... Luego me dije "casi hay que sumar al segundo y al tercero del stack para pillarle, yo creo que la rep. hace tiempo que ha dejado de ofrecerle un aliciente..."

Comment: @Charlie está bien, por suerte SE es user friendly y no se pierde el texto si el envío de la respuesta falla. Yo pensé en responder a la pregunta más antigua, pero es un criterio como otro cualquiera...

Comment: Vaya jaleo tenéis montado aquí :D @wimi el captcha sale si el sistema detecta que le das a enviar muy rápido. Supongo que copiaste el texto de la otra respuesta, lo pegaste aquí y le diste a enviar a los pocos segundos. El sistema debe pensar que no da tiempo de escribir tanto texto en tan poco tiempo y piensa que eres un robot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/una-charla-de-lo-mas-distendidodistendida/) dice que ambas opciones son válidas:

> **En la estructura *sustantivo + de lo más + adjetivo*, el adjetivo puede concordar en género y número con el sustantivo** (*una charla de lo más distendida*) **o permanecer en masculino singular** (*una charla de lo más distendido*), patrón predominante en la lengua escrita.

La única excepción que menciona el artículo es el caso en el que el adjetivo va seguido de una oración subordinada de relativo, en cuyo caso el adjetivo debe estar en masculino singular. El ejemplo que pone el artículo es:

> Una novela de lo más entretenido que he leído en años